# Percentage nature

Tags: percentages

In mathematical expressions, the internationally recognized symbol % (percent) may be used with the SI to represent the number 0.01. Thus, it can be used to express the values of dimensionless quantities. 
According to Le Système international d’unités/The International System of Units, (Brochure sur le SI/SI brochure), 2006.

In mathematics, a percentage is a number or ratio expressed as a fraction of 100. It is often denoted using the percent sign, "%", or the abbreviations "pct.", "pct"; sometimes the abbreviation "pc" is also used.[1] A percentage is a dimensionless number (pure number).
Based on Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage

Is percentage considered as a number?, e.i. can I add a number to percentage?

Is the following considered as a valid question?

Evaluate 30+10%

Answer: 30+10%=30.1

Comment: In your case it should be 30 + (1 + .10) = 33

Comment: I think your question is good.  If it does not get a good response here, consider asking it at [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you that $30+10\%=30+10\cdot 0.01=30.1$.  However, you asked "Is the following considered a valid question?" and I'm afraid that it would be very confusing for students.  That is, if a teacher asked "Evaluate $30+10\%$" in an exam, many students (and their parents) would complain because they would find it "unclear."  They are not accustomed to having pure numbers added with percentages.

Comment: In fact, many handheld calculators would evaluate $30+10\%$ as increasing $30$ by $10\%$ and do $30(1+0.1)=33$  I don't claim that is mathematically accurate, but many people have been trained by their calculators that way.  Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage is not a number: it's only a form or notation for a number, as well as, for example, scientific notation.

I write scientific notation not by accident. Consider, for any numer $c$, the following factorization, with $n$ arbitrary integer:
$$c=c^* \times 10^n.$$
When $1 \leq c^*<10$, then the above [is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) as scientific notation; when $n\mod 3 = 0$ it is called engineering notation.

But not everyone realizes that even percentage falls into such case: the one with $n=-2$ and the symbol % replacing the multiplication by $10^-2$.

So, for example, $0.15=15 \times 10^{-2}=15 \frac1{100}=15\%$.

You ask if 15% is a number or a percentage. I answer: it's a number in percentage form.

It's not the form that makes a number, but its value: 0.15, $\frac3{20}$, $1.5 \times 10^{-1}$, 15% are only different ways to express the same number.

So, yes, you can calculate 30+10%, because you aren't adding a number to a percentage: you are simply playing with two numbers expressed in different forms.

Anyway, I sometimes fell discomfort when speaking about percentages with colleagues and others, when reading textbooks and online resources, because they seem to have a different (but inconsistent) definition of percentage, where a multiplication by 100 plays a very detrimental role.

Even if I don't consider a ratio a prerequisite to have a percentage, many sources explain percentages starting from a ratio.

For example, some textbooks (most about chemistry, as far as I known) multiply a ratio by 100 and then add the symbol % to the result, as if it was a unit of measure to be written just one time (see for example [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/12248/why-are-percentages-part-of-the-curriculum#comment29642_12248) instance reported on Mathematics Educators). But $$\frac{15}{100} \times 100 = 15\%$$ is not a valid equality, according to the definition of the symbol %! One should <s>write "parts per hundred" in place of % next to the result or</s> (SI considers "parts per hundred" a synonym of %) multiply by 100% instead than by 100:
$$\frac{15}{100} \times 100\% = 15\%$$

Sadly, several Wikipedia pages contribute to such confusion.

For example, on the English Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage#Calculations) about percentage, we read:

> The percent value is computed by multiplying the numeric value of the
> ratio by 100. For example, to find 50 apples as a percentage of 1250
> apples, one first computes the ratio $\frac{50}{1250}=0.04$, and then
> multiplies by 100 to obtain 4%.

And then, paradoxically:

> It is not correct to divide by 100 and use the percent sign at the
> same time

when the most frequent error is another: to multiply by 100 and put it equal to the result followed by the % sign.

Here is another example from the French Wikipedia [page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pourcentage):

> Exemple : 56 personnes parmi 400 (population de référence) ont une
> particularité P. Pour exprimer cette proportion sur une population de
> 100, il faut diviser 400 par 4, et faire de même avec 56 pour
> conserver la proportion. Or 56 / 4 = 14. Donc 14 % ont une
> particularité P.
>
> Le calcul de ce pourcentage revient à trouver le numérateur d'une
> fraction dont le dénominateur serait 100 et qui serait égale à
> $\frac {56}{400}$. C'est ainsi
> que l'on confond souvent la fraction de dénominateur 100 avec le
> pourcentage et donc le pourcentage avec le nombre décimal 0,14.
>
> Cette confusion, très pratique en mathématique, induit parfois des
> incompréhensions dans le domaine technique puisque l'on rencontre
> souvent l'indication de calcul suivante : pourcentage de personne
> ayant la particularité P : $\frac{56}{400}\times 100=14$